# Is it possible to attach a redis container to a docker volume?

Tags: docker, redis, containers, docker-volume, redisjson

I'm using `ReJSON`, which a modified_enhanced version of redis. I'm wondering if that can affect the functionment of the common command.
I would persist my data, to make so, I have created a custom volume. But the data doesn't persist when I stop, then restart my container. [The official doc](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/redis/) talks about a `/data` directory to bind in order to mount the volume.

​

I have tried to do:

> ~$ docker run --name rejson -d -p 6384:6379 -v $PWD/volumes:/data   redislabs/rejson

I have also tested:

> ~$ docker run --name rejson -d -p 6384:6379 -v $PWD/volumes:/data   redislabs/rejson --appendonly

doesn't work either,

any hint would be great,

thanks

Comment: What about the commands does not work?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just following the example strictly?

```
docker run --name rejson -d -p 6384:6379 -v $PWD/volumes:/data redislabs/rejson --appendonly yes
```

There is `yes` argument in the example given. You mounts are correct.

Comment: thanks, now it didn't recognize the json commands anymore, it returns me `ERR unknown command json.get, with args beginning with: myVar`

Comment: @grapese how to pass that appendonly yes in kubernetes file ?

Comment: I had this same problem with it not recognizing the JSON commands.  I fixed it by repalcing `--appendonly yes` with `redis-server --loadmodule /usr/lib/redis/modules/rejson.so --appendonly yes`.  It seems like passing the appendonly yes argument ate the argument that loads the JSON operations.